# Pip install from Private Repo

Tags: python, git, github, pip

I am trying to pip install from a private repo. I can clone from my repo and push and pull and that works fine so I think my public and private keys are fine I have read as much as I could but can't seem to get around the error.

Using a Mac, Here is what I am trying.

```
(venv) Mac:Projects$ pip install git+ssh://git@github.com/private_repo/git_stuff.git#egg=git_stuff
```

Error:

```
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/private/var/folders/3d/s4d37gtgd1dfgfg18tmfd_nvsdfr1111gn/x/pip-install-abcdfs/git-stuff/setup.py'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/3d/s4d37gtgd1dfgfg18tmfd_nvsdfr1111gn/x/pip-install-7RccWF/git-stuff/
```

setup.py file on project

```
setuptools.setup(
    name="git_stuff",
    version="0.0.1",
    author="Example Author",
    author_email="test.com",
    description="A small example package",
    url="https://github.com/private_repo/git_stuff.git",
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
)
```

Things I have tried:

1. Updating setup tools. version setuptools   40.4.3
2. Updating pip . version 18.0

Python version 2.7.10

Comment: Do you have a `setup.py` in your project?

Comment: yep I just made an edit and included it

Comment: You should double check that. The error message indicates there is none.